# Webhid device opened, but oninputreport listener is not work

Tags: javascript, webhid

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>WebHID Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>WebHID Example</h1>
  <button id = 'requestDevice' >Open Device</button>
  <button id = 'openButton'>Open button</button>
  <div id="device-info"></div>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <script>
  let device;
requestDevice.onclick = async event => {
  document.body.style.display = "none";
  try {
    const filters = [
      {
        vendorId: 0x03F0, productId: 0x034A //keyboard
      }
    ];

    [device] = await navigator.hid.requestDevice({ filters });
    if (!device) return;
    console.log(device);
  } finally {
    document.body.style.display = "";
  }
};

openButton.onclick = async event => {
  await device.open();
  device.oninputreport = ({device, reportId, data}) => {
  console.log(`Input report ${reportId} from ${device.productName}:`,
              new Uint8Array(data.buffer));
  };
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my javascript code
When I Choose keyboard hid device and try to press any button, oninputreport listener is not work

thanks for your help!

i want to try how could hid device listener work, thanks!

The datastruct is below

[webhid keyboard datastruct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8I4T.png)

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard input events are on the [WebHID blocklist](https://wicg.github.io/webhid/#blocklist) and so will not generate `inputreport` events.

Comment: keyborad collections usage: 1,usagePage: 12, but i saw blockllist not contain this?

Comment: Usage 1 from usage page 12 is Consumer Control. On keyboards, a Consumer Control collection is commonly used for media key functionality (play, pause, stop, etc). Which keys are you pressing to test this?